# I want mysql query to return even if the result is null

Tags: mysql

I want a query to return even if the result is null.

I did this :

```
select
`orders`.id,
DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`createdAt`, '%d-%m-%Y') AS date_formatted,
count(`orders`.id)
from
`order_status` left JOIN `orders` AS `orders` ON `order_status`.id = `orders`.`orderStatus`  
where
  `orders`.`createdAt` >= '2017-05-05 00:00:00' AND
   `orders`.`createdAt` <= '2017-05-05 11:59:59'
group by
    1,2;
```

since that, i have table called orders has a column orderStatus and the other table called order_status.

Thanks...

Comment: it does return :D

Comment: Do you have null values in `createdAt` column and want those rows to be returned?

Comment: 1-no i don't have null value in createdAt.   2- yes